# What happened to the __get__ function in Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

The homepage on git for handlebars.js (https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) talks about a function called `__get__` under the Block Helpers section that can be used to retrieve path variables within the current context.  But it is not available within any helpers context/this.  Was it removed? Is there another way to retrieve path data from inside a helper?  In particular, a way to go up the ladder and retrieve parent data via the `../` path?

There is a 6 month old open issue with no discussion about it here:
https://github.com/donpark/hbs/issues/18

edit: This issue is not posted on handlebars project, but an extension which recognizes the same problem.

Comment: Handlebars is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/donpark/hbs/blob/master/Readme.md): "This project is frozen because I am no longer using Handlebars as primary template engine."

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: wrong github. Handlebars is [alive and well](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js).

Comment: @CrescentFresh Well I just used the one the OP linked to, so clearly they think that's the right one.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: apologies, that open issue is not on the handlebars project, but recognizes the same issue with handlebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the issue I filed here:
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/234

__get__ is no longer available, however if you pass 'this' in to the block explicitly you can access the parent's properties

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to reference a parent property then?  I was assuming it would be possible to do something like: `this.__get__("../parentId") `  Not sure how that would work using 'this'

Answer (score 0):

`__get__` issue is in [hbs](https://github.com/donpark/hbs/issues/18) project, not `Handlebars`.

New maintainer of `hbs` project just started looking at this issue so stay tuned. Thx.

Comment: thanks, but I think the issue is with Handlebars.  On their homepage of github, in the section titled "Block Handlers", they talk about this function and use in example, but it is not available when using Handlebars client side  (I don't even use hbs - I just mentioned that link to hbs since they talked about the same issue)